# OpenFileDialog does sometimes show empty navigation

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I show an OpenFileDialog with the following code:

```
var fileBox = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog
{
    InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop),
    Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*",
    FilterIndex = 1,
    Multiselect = true,
    CheckPathExists = true,
    CheckFileExists = true
};
var fileSelected = fileBox.ShowDialog(owner);
```

Mostly this works perfectly. But from time to time, the navigation at the left in the Dialog is shown as white rectangle. You can see that in this printscreen:

[image]

Does someone have an idea, why this appears?

Comment: This dialog is built into the OS, nothing to do with your code.  You can turn it off with Organize > Layout > Navigation Pane.  Superuser.com is a good place to ask why it has a problem filling the pane, I'd guess at some sort of drive or network timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... Not quite sure as to why this happens. Some sources say that the permission of a user might contribute, some people had to reboot stuff but most times the cause is that there is an inaccurate execution of codes by the system. So I'll suggest that you input a path yourself
eg:
 openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\owner\Documents\";

or if you're unsure of what drive(eg. C:) or user(eg: owner) will be using the system, you can obtain this information and concatenate or so. Hope this helps slightly.